# Allow Dynamic Media URL in Products and Categories setting gone?

Tags: magento2

I am running Magento 2.4.2 and I am not seeing to option to enable "Allow Dynamic Media URL in Products and Categories" under Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Storefront. How can I get media urls to work for category pages?

Comment: Check this documentation https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/catalog-urls-dynamic-media.html

Comment: Hi @RahulBarot of course I checked that first, but thats not having the right information. Look here https://magestandard.com/manage-dynamic-media-urls-in-magento-2/ then you can see we had or should have two settings for media urls. The one under content management is still there and enabled, but dynamic media is not working on category pages.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. This was caused by the IceCat Live plugin.